# Is it possible to animate an ::after based on a changing class?

Tags: css

I have a few elements

```
<div class="nav-link active"><span>Element 1</span></div>
<div class="nav-link"><span>Element 2</span></div>
<div class="nav-link"><span>Element 3</span></div>
```

where the active would change on click and css to add a red rhombus underneath the active div:

```
.nav .nav-link.active span::after{
content: "";
width: 120%;
height: 0.14em;
background: red;
transform: skewX(-45deg);
list-style: 0.5em;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
left: -20px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

and would like to change the position of that red rhombus on the `.nav-link` by having it animate slide in from the left based on if the div contains `.active`. However adding:

```
.nav .nav-link span::after{
    left: -200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

doesn't appear to work. Is this possible or am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: ya, you can used `translateX` with `skewX ` to animated slide left

Comment: that doesn't actually animate it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `translateX` to animated left slide.

```css
.nav .nav-link.active span::after{
  content: "";
  width: 120%;
  height: 0.14em;
  background: red;
  transform: skewX(-45deg) translateX(100px);
  list-style: 0.5em;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-link active"><span>Element 1</span></div>
  <div class="nav-link"><span>Element 2</span></div>
  <div class="nav-link"><span>Element 3</span></div>
</div>
```